# Equivalence of function types with type variables

Tags: function, haskell, types

I need a function with following attributes.

> (c->d)->(a->b->c)->a->b->d

my function:

funktionD  = (.) . (.)

but :t funktionD

> funktionD :: (a -> b) -> (c -> d -> a) -> c -> d -> b

ist this equal?

Comment: Why not substitute the type variables yourself and try it out?

Comment: You can also just write `funktionD :: (c->d)->(a->b->c)->a->b->d` above your function definition, and if the types are wrong the compiler will tell you so.

Comment: @MatrixFrog: That's also an excellent suggestion. Never underestimate the value of preemptively arguing with the Haskell compiler. Just because it always wins the argument doesn't mean you can't learn something in the process!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is. Type variables--written in lowercase--are just that, variables. You can rename them all you like as long as the pattern of which are the same variable stays the same.

Furthermore, for essentially the same reason, for the type signature you gave there is only one possible function of that type (excluding functions that crash or go into infinite loops, that is). Something to think about!

Answer (score 2):

I think it is. Replace a with c (and vice versa), then replace b with d (and vice versa) and they are the same.